# Windows Phone 8.1 - Getting a scaled down image before loading it

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a Windows Phone 8.1 app (Windows Runtime, not Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1). In my app I need to work with images. If the image is 12MP or less, everything works fine, but if the image is too large, let's say, for example, 41MP, an OutOfMemoryException is thrown.
I know that with BitmapImage you can set the DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight property to make the image smaller before even decoding it.
But I need to work with WriteableBitmap. So, is there a way to convert a BitmapImage into a WriteableBitmap? If not, how can I set the WriteableBitmap to be scaled down before even decoding its content?

My code is as follows:

```
StorageFolder installationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        string imagePath = @"Assets\trees201205150056_1337809980.jpg";
        StorageFile file = await installationFolder.GetFileAsync(imagePath);
        using(Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            testPreviewImage.Source = writeableBmp;
            writeableBmp = null;
        }
```

With BitmapImage it would be something like this:

```
StorageFolder installationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        string imagePath = @"Assets\trees201205150056_1337809980.jpg";
        StorageFile file = await installationFolder.GetFileAsync(imagePath);
        using(Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage { DecodePixelWidth = 2000};
            testPreviewImage.Source = bitmapImage;
            bitmapImage = null;
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need specifically a WriteableBitmap? In a WriteableBitmap, a pixel is stored as an int and uses 4 bytes. So a 41 MP picture would use 41000000 * 4 = 164000000 bytes. That is roughly 160 MB. No matter what you do, you can't load the entire picture without hitting the memory limit. When making the Lumia 1020, Nokia was aware of this problem and released the Imaging SDK. It allows you to edit a picture by loading only parts of it at a time. It's the tool you're supposed to use in your situation.

Comment: Because I need to draw some lines over the image, and for this reason I need to have a WriteableBitmap